# check if string contains both number and letter (at least)

Tags: regex

I wish to check if a password contains at least one letter and a number. special characters are accepted but not required...

That will be a simple password checker.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use lookahead assertions to check for existence of any digit and any letter as:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])
```

Comment: You could drop the `.*$` part.

Comment: this is wrong, and test string that contain letters **OR** numbers.

i found answer by "Pete Lindquist" here: https://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=515

Expression 
   ```(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15})$```
 Matches
  ```C2dfeed | sporttrak1 | 11223a```

Comment: Desc:
...This expression tests negatively for all number cases, then all letter cases, and lastly tests for only alphanumeric characters in the required range. In other words: the match must be alphanumeric with at least one number, one letter, and be between 6-15 character in length.

Comment: This is wrong. @calios is right. Confirmed!

Answer (score 8):

Using a single regex for this can lead to somewhat unreadable/unreliable code. It may make more sense to use simpler regexes eg `[0-9]` to check for the existence of a digit and break the requirements of your password strength checker into a multi-line `if`. Also this allows you to know more readily at what stage the validation failed and possibly make suggestions to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution to check for password containing at least one letter, at least one digit and no spaces:

```
\S*(\S*([a-zA-Z]\S*[0-9])|([0-9]\S*[a-zA-Z]))\S*
```

Comment: How does this differ from / improve the existing answers? It is preferable to include a description, especially in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

```
([0-9].*[a-zA-Z])\|([a-zA-Z].*[0-9])
```

Not sure if the pipe needs to be escaped in your regexp environment or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
/.*?(?:[a-z].*?[0-9]|[0-9].*?[a-z]).*?/
```

(just *one* possible solution)

Comment: What about capital letters? Also what does `.*?` do exactly and how come you use it before the `|` but not in the bit afterwards?

Comment: Add an `i` flag, the `*?` is a greedy match (google it). And I forgot to do it in the second part of the pipe.

Comment: Isn't `*?` a *non*-greedy match?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
/^(\d+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+\d)(\d|[a-zA-Z])*/mg
```