# How can I verify an input parameter format?

Tags: angularjs

I would like some specific help and advice on using `ng-pattern`.

I have the following rules:

- Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character.
- Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9').
- Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').

On my front-end I have this in the HTML:

```
<span ng-show="regForm.password.$dirty &&
               !regForm.password.$error.required &&
               !regForm.password.$error.minlength &&
               (aus.password != aus.confirmPassword)">
  Passwords do not match
</span>
```

Is there a way that I can create other `ng-show`s that would test if the input met the other three rules with `ng-pattern`?

Here's my `<input>`

```
<input id="password"
       name="password"
       ng-model="aus.password"
       ng-minlength="6"
       ng-required="true"
       type="password"
       value="" />
```

Hope someone can help me with an answer to this that uses **ng-pattern**. Please note that this is **not a duplicate question to using an HTML regex**. I am looking for specific `ng-pattern` help.

Comment: I think adding custom validator is correct here since you not only need to validate, but show appropriate error message.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - do you have any suggestions as to how this could be done.  Thanks, M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building a regular expression for `ng-pattern` that expects a digit *and* an uppercase letter *and* a special character can get hard to manage, though there are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429847/check-if-string-contains-both-number-and-letter-at-least) SO [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928092/need-a-regex-for-a-string-that-must-have-both-numeric-and-letter-characters) around that will set you in that direction. As [@Petr Averyanov suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546772/how-can-i-verify-an-input-parameter-format#comment54874186_33546772), custom validators are a better way to go. They're more flexible, easier to maintain, and let you separate your various error cases into different messages to the user.

Read up on them in the **Custom Validation** section of [Angular's Forms documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/guide/forms). Pop open this snippet for a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('validationDemo', ['ngMessages']);

app.directive('strongPassword', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.containsSpecial = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) { return true; }
        if (/[^a-z0-9]/i.test(viewValue)) { return true; }
        return false;
      };
      
      ctrl.$validators.containsDigit = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) { return true; }
        if (/\d/.test(viewValue)) { return true; }
        return false;
      };
      
      ctrl.$validators.containsUppercase = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) { return true; }
        if (/[A-Z]/.test(viewValue)) { return true; }
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>

<body ng-app="validationDemo">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <div>
      Password:
      <input type="text" ng-model="password" name="password" strong-password /><br />
      {{password}}
      <ul ng-messages="form.password.$error" multiple="true">
        <li ng-message="containsSpecial">
          Your password must contain at least one non-letter, non-digit character
        </li>
        <li ng-message="containsDigit">
          Your password must contain at least one digit
        </li>
        <li ng-message="containsUppercase">
          Your password must contain at least one uppercase letter
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

You start by declaring a [directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/guide/directive) for your validators. We'll call this one `strongPassword`.

```
var app = angular.module('validationDemo', []);

app.directive('strongPassword', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      // Validators go here
    }
  };
});
```

Attach the directive to your password `input` as an HTML attribute, with the usual camelCase to dash-separated conversion.

```
<body ng-app="validationDemo">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <div>
      Password:
      <input type="text" ng-model="password" name="password" strong-password /><br />
      {{password}}
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

For each validation you want to add, set a key in your directive on `ctrl.$validators`. So to validate that the password contains a digit,

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
  ctrl.$validators.containsDigit = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) { return true; } // They haven't typed yet
    if (/\d/.test(viewValue)) { return true; } // Found a digit
    return false;
  };
}
```

Then you get access to errors on `form.<element name>.$error`, in this case `form.password.$error.containsDigit`. Use the `ng-messages` directive (make sure to import `angular-messages.js`) to display the errors to your user.

```
<ul ng-messages="form.password.$error" multiple="true">
  <li ng-message="containsDigit">
    Your password must contain at least one digit
  </li>
</ul>
```

The value to `ng-messages` is the error object on the form, and each `ng-message` describes a key on `$error` with a value you want to print. The `multiple` option tells Angular to display all messages at once; otherwise, you get just one at a time.

Comment: you have another option of using the ngMessages api, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages,                  which is very user friendly and very understandable, and reduces the amount of code you should write for the showing\hiding of the messages

Comment: @RanSasportas Thanks! I converted the code to use `ng-messages`, that's somewhat nicer.